# Wants to get selected index fron a JList. But returns -1

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I made a jlist and set a default list model using setModel method. When I called getSelectedIndex(), it returns -1. Why is it?

```
if (!listAdded.isSelectionEmpty()) {
        listModelAdded.removeElementAt(listAdded.getSelectedIndex());
        listBankQuestions.remove(listAdded.getSelectedIndex());
        System.out.println(i);
        --i;
        System.out.println("Selected : " + listAdded.getSelectedIndex());
}
```

Comment: Because there's nothing selected??

Comment: I assure. I selected an item of list

Comment: Does it print out -1 in the first `System.out.println`? My guess is that it wouldn't or else the previous lines would throw an error. So, the only thing left to assume is that when you remove the element that is currently selected, obviously there is nothing selected anymore, therefore, returning a value of -1.

Comment: I printed the selected index value in valueChanged event. It works correctly. I didn't get any exception.

Comment: @RSST It sounds like you could be shadowing your variables. Knowing you did something and actually doing it on the right instance of the right object is something else.  You'll get a better answer if your provided a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: `"I assure. I selected an item of list"` -- I strongly urge you to not make any assumptions like this until your problem is solved. There is only one reason for -1 to be seen, and that is that the JTable you are checking has no selected items at the time you are checking it. I can "assure" you that your assumption is incorrect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method [`getSelectedIndex()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedIndex%28%29) returns `-1` if no item is selected

Comment: I selected an item. It returns -1.

Comment: @RSST - The JVM disagrees with you.  Or more precisely ... by the time you called the method, no item was selected.

Answer (score 3):

The javadoc clearly states that [`getSelectedIndex()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedIndex%28%29) returns -1 if no item is selected.

If you are seeing `-1` when you believe that you shouldn't, then I can think of three explanations:

- Something else (in your code) is removing the selection *before* the `getSelectedIndex()` call happens.
- You are accessing the Swing data structures incorrectly.  If you try to access them from some other thread than the event listener thread, there is no guarantee that it will see the correct state.
- You are somehow misreading the symptoms; e.g. you are calling `getSelectedIndex()` on the wrong object.

(A final possibility is "its a Swing bug" ... but before anyone could make that call, you'd need to provide a proper SSCCE that demonstrates the problem.  And frankly, I think it is highly unlikely that this really is a Swing bug.)

Answer (score 0):

Because you removed the selected item, then there is no selection (selection Removed) and the return value is -1

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I had to use .locationToIndex because .getSelectedIndex wasn't working correctly with right-clicking, returning -1.  Here's some working code:

```
tileSelector.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // get Selected Tile
        int idx = tileSelector.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
        tileSelector.setSelectedIndex(idx);
        if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
            debugOutput.append(idx + " Left Click\n");
            debugOutput.setCaretPosition(debugOutput.getDocument().getLength());
        } else if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
            debugOutput.append(idx + " Right Click\n");
            debugOutput.setCaretPosition(debugOutput.getDocument().getLength());
        }
    }
});
```